# How to get z to show up properly in Pyplot math mode

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex

I'm trying to create an axis label for a graph made using matplotlib.pyplot, and I'm using math mode for subscripts and superscripts.  However, whenever I try to put a z inside math mode, it instead comes out as an approximately equals sign.  Anyone know how to fix it?  It shows up normally if I put it outside math mode, but that puts an unacceptable space between the H and the z.  Here's my python program:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

h = 6.626e-34
c = 3.0e+8
k = 1.38e-23

def planck(w):
    intensity = 2*h*w**3/((c**2)*(np.exp(h*w/(k*10000))-1))
    return intensity

    wavelength = np.logspace(-4,16,1000)  

intensity = planck(wavelength)

plt.loglog(wavelength,intensity,'k')
plt.ylim([1e-20,1e-6])
plt.xlim([1e7,1e17])

plt.ylabel(r"$I_\nu \ (W m^{-2} \! {Hz}^{-1} \!  sr^{-1})$")
plt.show()
```

On another note, is there a way to increase the size of specific characters inside of math mode in matplotlib?

Comment: `z` kind of looks like an approx. equal sign when its top and bottom strokes are curvy and  the middle one is very thin.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an approximately-equals sign, it's just an italic z whose diagonal stroke is invisible in the font and size you're using.  Making it bigger clarifies things:

```
plt.ylabel(r"$I_\nu \ (W m^{-2} \! {Hz}^{-1} \!  sr^{-1})$", fontsize="x-large")
```